# Установка хука на мышь

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Есть консольное приложение с таким кодом

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hproc = new Hooks.HookProc(Hooks.MouseHookProc);
    var hHook = Hooks.SetWindowsHookEx(Hooks.WH_MOUSE, hproc, (IntPtr)0, AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
    Console.WriteLine(hHook);
    Console.ReadKey();
    Hooks.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
}
```

а вот класс Hooks и парочка структур

```
public class Hooks
{
    public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    static int hHook = 0;
    public const int WH_MOUSE = 7;

    // Повесить хук
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    // Убрать хук
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    // Послать то что выловили дальше
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode,IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static int MouseHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        var MyMouseHookStruct = (MouseHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseHookStruct));

        if (nCode < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
        else
        {
            var strCaption = "x = " +
                    MyMouseHookStruct.pt.x.ToString("d") +
                        "  y = " +
            MyMouseHookStruct.pt.y.ToString("d");
            Console.WriteLine(strCaption);
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class MouseHookStruct
{
    public POINT pt;
    public int hwnd;
    public int wHitTestCode;
    public int dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Как я понял, процедура MouseHookProc должна вызываться при действиях мышью. Но ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А у вас есть уверенность что хук установился? SetWindowsHookEx() вернул не 0 ?

Comment: @nzeemin, , не 0

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать в MouseHookProc всё кроме вызовов CallNextHookEx() и добавьте Console.WriteLine() в самом начале метода. Если ничего не пишется -- значит надо копать в сторону правильного указания типов для маршаллинга.

Comment: @nzeemin, в этом нет необходимости. Я ставил точку останова в начале этой функции. Безрезультатно. Захода туда нет

Comment: может нужно в классе: public int hHook = 0; а потом после получения его присвоить в класс: Hooks.hHook = Hooks.SetWindowsHookEx(Hooks.WH_MOUSE, hproc, (IntPtr)0, AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());

Comment: @Konst, эта переменная не имеет там значения

Comment: но его значение необходимо для работы самого хука, иначе там будет 0 во всех внутренних вызовах CallNextHookEx

Comment: @Konst, об этом я подумаю после того, как попаду в эту функцию

Comment: @Konst, я же написал, эта функция вообще не выполняется. Я ставил там точку останова, и ничего...

Comment: я не уверен, но точки останова могут не работать. попробуйте выводить в консоль в начале метода

Comment: @Konst, ничего не изменилось

Comment: посмотрите пример для winforms, начните с него: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/318804

Comment: @Konst, спасибо, мой код взят именно оттуда :)

Answer (score -1):

`WH_MOUSE = 7;` замените на `WH_MOUSE_LL = 14`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?